# Get file size in Automator workflow

Tags: bash, service, filesize, automator

Creating a service in Automator (Run shell script > Bash) to copy to clipboard filesize (in bytes) of selected file in Finder. I'm not very well versed in bash, and can't see where this is wrong.
Aim is to have it appear in the 'services' menu when right clicking a file, and then I can just paste the filesize wherever I fancy.
Options I have selected in Automator are:

Service receives selected "files or folders" in "Finder.app"

Shell /bin/bash

Pass input as arguments

```
for f in "$@"
do
    getty=$(ls -l "$f")
done

IFS=' ' read -a newList <<< "${getty}"

echo -n ${newList[4]} | pbcopy
```

Run Shell Script failed - 1 error:

-: -c: line1: syntax error near unexpected token `do

Comment: Can you summarise your requirement in a better way for us to provide/suggest a better solution than this?

Comment: sure, edited question

Comment: What is passed in the argument? What property are you trying to store in `getty`? and what is there in `${newList[4]}`

Comment: The property I am trying to store is the filesize in bytes from ls -l . 
newlist should then be that value too, taken from getty

Comment: But I have questions? why is it present outside the loop? You don't need to parse ls output at all. If I understand your requirement right, you want to get the size of the file name being passed to `pbcopy`?

Comment: Sorry, the value from ls -l becomes the filesize when I select [4] from newList

Comment: Use the answer below and not use `ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clearer to everyone, the solution is :

1. create an empty automator script
2. add action "get selected elements from Finder
3. add action "Run shell script" with inputs as arguments
4. with the following script :

> ```
>  stat -f  '%z' "$@" | pbcopy
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `ls`, use `stat` to get the file size.

```
stat -f '%z' "$f" | pbcopy
```

To copy, say, the name and size of a group of files to the clipboard:

```
stat -f '%N %z' "$@" | pbcopy
```

Comment: `++`, exactly how it should be

Comment: Nice, this works great. I've removed %N in mine so the copy to clipboard is just the filesize, not the filepath too

Comment: Sure; I just tossed that in to show how to add multiple fields, and to distinguish one size from another if you need to. See the `stat` man page for all data you can display for each input file.